# java applet run local host but doesn't run after publish iis , By asp.net

Tags: java, asp.net, iis, applet, localhost

I embedded java applet in my asp.net web site to make digital signature  , it work greet in local host , but when publish it , java applet run on browser but 
java script code that call function on java applet is not defined

```
codesignApplet = document.getElementById('SignApplet'); 
signApplet.SetCertificate()
```

So when call  SetCertificate in local host it run as we want , 
but when call it in published >error >> SetCertificate  is not a function

ASPX Applet Code

```html
<applet id="SignApplet" jnlp_href="sign.jnlp" width="100" height="100">
<param name="inputtype" value="file">
<param name="outputtype" value="file">
<param name="inputfile" id="param_input" value="File Path HERE">
<param name="outputfile" id="param_output" value="File Path HERE">
</applet>
```

Note : local host and published site run at same browser and same security setting  to run java applet

Comment: HTML (what ASPX produces for the browser) has a specific form and rules, and they do not include adding an `id` to `param` elements (you can't just make it up as you go along)!  [Validate the HTML](http://validator.w3.org/) produced by the ASPX.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally i found solution  for this issue  , the jnlp file ( With java applet ) need initialization in IIS to can read it

I must add Mime Type :

Extension: .jnlp ,
Mime Type: application/x-java-jnlp-file

and this link explain how add mime type in IIS 
https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc725608%28v=ws.10%29.aspx

I try this and it work Great, i prefer share my answer to help other in my one favorite  site :)